# Whats the good way check and compare data (time limit) from database in Java?

Tags: java, database, algorithm, methods

So, I have a mysql db, and lets say we have `donation` table, and I have a Java application.
My donation table have columns such as: `user_id`, `tier`, `start_date`, and `end_date`. Both `start_date` and `end_date` is bigInteger and have miliseconds time format.

I already coded and worked the insertion method in Java, so I can insert the start_date, and the end_date (end_date=start_date+30 days) and other columns data to the table.

What I don't understand is what is the best way to check and lets say, a method to demote the user back to the default tier when the server time is equals with end_date from the db.

Should I check every minutes/hours if servertime > end_date? (I think this way is somewhat redundant and performance hungry to the system)
Or are there a better way to do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This would best be done with some type of scheduling, like a timer that is configured to fire at `end_date` for instance. So research the availability of any such 3rd party library or roll your own.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I just afraid its memory/resource consuming for the system. I will try to use the timer. ;)

Comment: I don't understand your reply, what is memory consuming?

Comment: Sorry, I meant is that I just afraid that the timer will have a great performance impact for the server.

Answer (score 1):

You could load a chunk (the next n) endDates (ordered) from DB and keep them in RAM. here you can keep them ordered and trigger an event (polling or a sleeping thread) when the top element passes the servertime.
When all your endDates in RAM are over, read the next chunk from DB.

This way you keep the frequency of db queries low and also the RAM usage (by selecting an n suited for your application).